# How to concatenate sentences in the same column in CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's say I have a specific column D with a sentence in each row in a CSV file, as such:

```
Hello.
Goodbye.
Maybe.
```

How would I go about concatenating them so I print them in sequence as: `Hello. Goodbye. Maybe.`? When I print them individually, I get the strings with quotes around them: `('Hello.')('Goodbye.')('Maybe')`.

Comment: one option would be to do `print(' '.join(myDataFrame['D'].tolist()))`

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: You don't event need to convert the column to a list: `" ".join(df["D"])`